# Can I continue training a deep neural network model with additional data?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, convolution

I have a model to train on speech data. At the beginning I always train from epoch 0 as I have small dataset. As my dataset gets bigger, I wonder, is it a valid practice to train with additional data on an existing model?

For example, I have a model trained with 100,000 samples and 30 epochs. Then I add 20,000 samples, and start training on 30 epochs and lasts for another 10 epochs on the entire dataset of 120,000 samples. How much will this affect the result (my metric is accuracy)?

Answer (score -1):

I would fear for overfitting on your additional 20,000 samples. I would do it like this randomly sample 20.000 from your initial dataset, then, add the new 20.000 and train for 30 epochs. In each epoch use different samples from the initial dataset. This should give you similar results, then by training on the full dataset.